# Determine user's input if it is an integer or a double?

Tags: java, integer, double

I have this code:

```
    kb.useDelimiter("\\b*[\\s]*");
    int answer = 0;
    String num1, num2;
    char operator;

    System.out.print("Enter calculation: "); // user will input **1+6**

    num1 = kb.nextInt();
    operator = kb.next().charAt(0);
    num1 = kb.nextInt();

    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':
            if (num1.hasNextInt)
            {
                 int aa= Integer.parseInt(num1);
                 int bb= Integer.parseInt(num2);
                answer = CalculatorMethods.add(aa,bb);
            }
            else
            {
                 //converts the String into Double
            }
            break;
    }
```

What im trying to do in this code is, the user can input in the program directly like this 1+1 . And what i did is i separate each so it will have 1, + and 1...
and if the user inputs an integer number.... then i will convert it to an integer and then calls the method.... else it will convert the String into a double and will then call the method..

So, when i compile the code above, all i get is MANY ERRORS like incompatible types, cannot find symbol hasNextInt.... what is wrong in my code?

ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: i change it to what you said.... but it still gives an "cannot find symbol hasNextInt()" error

Comment: num1 & num2 are strings. You try to set there an int. (nextInt). And num1&num2 dont have hasNextInt() method. Many strange things there.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `num1` variable is declared as a String, but you are trying to assign an int to it (i'm assuming kb is an instance of a Scanner). Then you are trying to invoke `num1.hasNextInt()` which is not a method of a String - i think you meant to say `kb.hasNextInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` returns `int`
so you can not do  `num1 = kb.nextInt();`

neither `String` or `int` have `hasNextInt`

You must declare `num1` and `num2` as `int`.

And some changes in switch case:

```
case '+':

                answer = CalculatorMethods.add(num1,num2);
          break;
```

Comment: if i change something like that in the switch case then i wont be able to know if the user inputs an integer or a double

Comment: First of all look on the `Scanner` class. You are confusing me. pls take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Answer (score 0):

Create one API that will tell you your string is integer or double type

```
public boolean isInteger(String value) { 
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(value);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then,

```
if (isInteger(num1) && isInteger(num2)){ // then check if it is integer do integer operation
   int aa= Integer.parseInt(num1);
   int bb= Integer.parseInt(num2);
   answer = CalculatorMethods.add(aa,bb);
}else{
     //converts the String into Double
}
```